# Remote Site Settings are deactivated in Patch Org

Tags: managed-package, patch, remote-site-settings

I recently found out that when i create a patch org from packaging org, **Remote site settings in patch org populate as deactivated.**

I was not aware of this and i released a patch. Now when i upgrade an existing package with this patch, remote site settings remain active and don't cause any issue.

But when i install this patch as fresh install these settings are disabled and due to this package throws errors.

1. I am not sure if it is a salesforce bug, can you guys please
   confirm?
2. Also Is there any list of components which might change in patch
   org?

**PS:** Solution of this is pretty simple that I can either activate them after installation of patch or activate them in patch and then release patch but why in patch they are getting deactivated and what is the need of making them deactivated?

Answer (score 3):

This is an expected behavior. I ran into this issue too and checked with SF support team. You have to make sure that every time you create a new patch org you should activate the remote site settings in that patch org.
 This is similar to when a newly added remote site settings are deployed via push upgrade and are deactivated in the customer org for security.

Comment: Are you aware of any other component which might get changed in patch?

Comment: Just adding here, I think it is also true if you have CSP  Trusted Sites as part of managed package